# How to toggle class inside a loop of items in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to vue.js and have this list of items:

```
<div class="jokes" v-for="joke in jokes">
    <strong>{{joke.body}}</strong>
    <small>{{joke.upvotes}}</small>
    <button v-on:click="upvote"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up grey"></i></button>
<div>
```

I want to toggle the `grey` to `green` when user clicks `upvote` button, so that the user knows what jokes she upvoted.

in the methods I have:

```
  data () {
    return {
        jokes:[], //filled dynamically by calling backend server
        id: ''

    }
  },

methods: {
    upvote: function(joke) {
        joke.upvotes ++;
        //how to toggle grey to green here?
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this? I have tried different tricks but all the tutorials change the class ALL of the items, not the one up-voted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the joke to the method, first of all.

```
v-on:click="upvote(joke)"
```

Then you need to add a v-class to it.   Either with v-bind:class, or just :class.

```
<div class="jokes" v-for="joke in jokes">
  <strong>{{joke.body}}</strong>
  <small>{{joke.upvotes}}</small>
  <button v-on:click="upvote(joke)"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" :class="{ green : joke.upvotes>0, grey: joke.upvotes<=0 }"></i></button>
<div>
```

[EXAMPLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/p4ha92x1/1/)

EDIT UPDATE.  To have it only affect the one you clicked on, and not all upvoted jokes.  You need a property on the joke, to know whether you selected it or not.
So lets say

```
joke.selected
```

Then...

```
<div class="jokes" v-for="joke in jokes">
  <strong>{{joke.body}}</strong>
  <small>{{joke.upvotes}}</small>
  <button v-on:click="upvote(joke)"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" :class="{green: joke.selected, grey: !joke.selected}"></i></button>
<div>
```

Then in your method

```
upvote: function(joke) {
   joke.upvotes++;
   if(!joke.selected){
        joke.selected=true;
   }
```

}

[EXAMPLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/p4ha92x1/2/)

Comment: It does not work. I guess because `joke.upvotes>0` it not a suitable conditionals. Supposes that the joke.upvotes is already>0 since it is upvoted by others. changing the class should not depend on that value.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the joke as an argument??  Thats an easy one to miss.  upvote(joke)

Comment: Well the joke.upvotes value comes from backend database. I removed that part for the sake of simplicity.   but `joke.upvoted` is a local to the user so has nothing to do the backend.

Comment: The difference of my case with the jsfiddle of yours is that in my data I have `jokes:[]` and it's dynamically filled with data received through axios.

Comment: The fact that youre using Axios, vs my object, shouldnt matter at all.  Forget joke.upvoted.  Do my second suggestion.  :class="{ green : joke.upvotes>0, grey: joke.upvotes<=0 }  Dont need the boolean, reads straight from the upvotes and applies the class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152541/discussion-between-karlom-and-kylek).